# Can not output a string in winmips64 normally

Tags: mips, mips64

```
# false code...
#          .data 
#str1:     .asciiz "plz enter two numbers:\n"
#str2:     .asciiz "warning: result overflow\n"
#str3:     .asciiz "the result:\n"
#CONTROL:  .word32 0x10000
#DATA:     .word32 0x10008


# right code...

          .data 
str1:     .asciiz "please enter two numbers:\n" # when I change 'please' to 'plz', something wrong happends! why?
str2:     .asciiz "the Result:\n"
str3:     .asciiz "Waring:result overflow!\n"
CONTROL:  .word32 0x10000
DATA:     .word32 0x10008


    .text
main:
    lwu r21,CONTROL(r0)
      lwu r22,DATA(r0)
    daddi r24,r0,4        ;set string output
    daddi r1,r0,str2      ;get address of str1
       sd r1,(r22)        ;wirte DATA
       sd r24,(r21)       ;print

    halt
```

I want to print a string on winmips64. It shows nothing in **false** code, but it works in **right** code. In right code, I try to change 'please' into 'plz' in str1 and it does not work again, why?

Comment: Your `CONTROL` and `DATA` variables may have become unaliagned depending on the length of the strings that preceed them. Remember that you can only use `lwu` with word-aligned addresses. Consult the assembler manual for how to properly align data (e.g. the `.align` directive).

Comment: Actually, it cannot run correctly even when I add .align 8 or 4 or 32 or ...